# Should I resize images for a mobile site

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple question that I would like to ask those who has a much better knowledge than I do.

The basis of the question is. When developing a mobile website. Should I dynamically resize the images that I get from external sources to be smaller. Or should I leave them as big images and handle it with css?

The Mobile website I am building pulls a lot of images from a webservice as base 64. Now my train of thought is this. I want to keep the size of my website as small as possible, thus resizing the images to be smaller seems to be a good idea.

On the other hand. Resizing the images with javascript, (lead developer wants everything done client side only...), might cause overhead for the user's mobile device.

What are your opinions on this matter. Should I resize the images or not ?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: _“The Mobile website I am building pulls a lot of images from a webservice as base 64”_ – outch. Base64 means a significant amount of overhead over “real” binary data already. (So at least use GZIP to minify that negative factor as much as possible.)

Comment: Backend is unfortunately not my work. Another idea that might also work is pulling a url from the website instead of base 64. Very good point you added there!

Comment: _“Resizing the images with javascript”_ – not sure what you exactly mean by that; usually you would resize an image client-side by just setting _dimensions_ for the image (via HTML attributes or CSS), and not _implement_ actual image resizing algorithms in JS. Anyway, resizing also cost computing power, and that might be a rather scarce resource on a not top-of-the-line mobile device, and in any case reflects on _battery_ power consumption.

Comment: The site will also allow the upload of images. Resizing them with javascript is one way to minimize upload size. But for downloaded images, resizing them is unnecessary, as setting your html elements up correctly will fix your resizing issue.

Comment: Another point to consider: Many mobile connection providers proxy requests through their own servers and apply additional image compression there, or the user might use an external service (like the new Opera Max) for that to save traffic/bandwidth – and I’m not sure how those handle really big images. Harsh compression on those plus resizing to smaller dimensions on the client might result in worse image quality in the end, than serving an appropriately sized image in the first place.

Comment: Yes. In opera mini you can set the quality of the images being loaded. A small trick I learned as a student when data rates were even more expensive back then! :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always be mindful of the mobile user's connection. Latency is often much higher on a mobile connection (so try to limit the overall number of requests, regardless of size), transfer rates are slower, and overage charges tend to be expensive.

In most cases the best solution is to serve an image that is roughly the size needed by the browser. Size "tweaks" in the browser are fine. Serving a somewhat larger image will allow for higher-quality zoom, but you should use this judiciously (does the image actually *need* to show more detail when zoomed?)

Also be mindful of the server-side expense of resizing the image every time it is requested. It's better to size once and then persist the result either to a cache or to a database.

[Facebook takes this approach](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=76191543919). As of 2009, they were generating and storing four different versions of each image.

If you must consume the full-size images in the mobile browser, at least try to lazy load them so that they are only downloaded when needed (e.g. when they are first scrolled into view).

Comment: This is very true!! We are based in South Africa and Data rates on mobile devices are very expensive here. I enjoyed the article you cited. There are very few places that large images are needed. If possible webservice should return smaller images. I like your answer very much. You broadened the discussion a lot and added a lot of content that I did not think of. Lazy load is a great idea, especially since the site will have a photo gallery section. Thank you for your great answer.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach I know - to use on of the existing Responsive Images solution.

I.e.:

- For backend side - http://adaptive-images.com/
- Frontend - https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill

Your could choose the one which is better for your. It depends on project.

If you have only mobile website - provide smaller images for it and save time and traffic for your users. If you can't - just scale it by css.